# Image files were deleted by itself in AWS-S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-django-storages

I'm using python Django framework for server and AWS-S3 for store uploaded image.
Also, i'm using django-storages library for handle S3.
But sometimes images were deleted by itself not through django server.
Image urls were still exist in DB.
So i changed create, put, delete, get action to get in bucket policy
But still deleted by itself.

django-storages setting in settings.py is this

```
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = S3['secret_key']
AWS_REGION = 'ap-northeast-2'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'loopusimage'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.%s.amazonaws.com' % (
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME, AWS_REGION)
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 1024000000
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 1024000000
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage
```

and changed bucket policy is this

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::loopusimage/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

What should i do to solve my problem?

Comment: S3 objects don't just delete themselves, either you have a lifecycle policy set up or someone is actively deleting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS itself will never delete items in the S3 but there are some scenarios that can be applicable to your problem.

1. You have set a [lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) for the items in your bucket. You can check AWS doc to see how to disable/check that.
2. The second problem you might have is the way you are storing the images in your models. You might have set the names in the wrong way which leads images to override each other in S3. I strongly recommend checking this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) to specify where to save the files.

To find your exact problem, you can use AWS CloudTrail. This service will help you to see who(or what) has deleted these images from your bucket. You can check this [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-audit-deleted-missing-objects/) for instruction.

Comment: i didn't set a lifecycle and images were irregularly delete not all of images that expired the date. and All of the upload images are cropped by flutter image cropper and image upload to folder (classified by upload date). so override shouldn't be happend..

Comment: @ysJ So, let's check the cloud trail to see what happened.